# Trying to limit the information shown in certain transactions depending on roles

Tags: authentication, permissions, abap, roles, sap-basis

Good day!

So I've been investigating for a way to limit the information shown in transactions depending on the user's role.

This means that for a transaction that has (already filled) fields for customer's name, address, date of birth and cash flow, if an accountant enters such transaction he'll only see the cash flow. Meanwhile, if an analyst enters the transaction, he'll be able to see everything.

I've been investigating and found information regarding authorization objects, but haven't been able to do anything.

If anyone has documentation and/or has done something similar and might be able to lead me into the correct direction, I'll appreciate it.

Kind regards,
Eduardo García.

Comment: This is not a programming-related question and therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow - that is, unless you're willing and able to redesign the entire application in question, which is usually a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

In best cases, you will find authorizations that would prevent the users from accessing the data but it won't hide the controls on the screen (unless explicitly designed but it is a tremendous effort).

Possible approaches:

- Create **transaction variant** to remove unnecessary elements (http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Transaction+Variant+-+A+Step+by+Step+Guide+for+Creation)
- Use **SAP Screen Personas** (requires and add-on) to redesign existing SAP Gui screens (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cd8XAvou2aU) including removing elements but also "pimp up" the screens in the same processs (this is especially useful for occasional users who often "reject" SAP Gui screens)

I would advise against creating a copy of standard transactions (what I often see) for such simple requirements because it becomes a mess to maintain in the long term with few added value.